# Count the occurrences of unequal numbers from a data frame

Tags: r, distance

I have a data frame df with four columns. I would like to find the number of unequal number for each pair of rows.

I have tried to do it using for loop and it works out perfectly. However, it take a very long time to run. Please see below my code:

```
dist_mat <- matrix(0, nrow(df), nrow(df))
for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
  for(j in 1:nrow(df))
  {
    dist_mat[i,j] <- sum(df[,1:4][i,]!=df[,1:4][j,])  
  }  
}
```

I thought there would be other way of doing this fast. Any suggestion is appreciated.

P.S. The data is numeric.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the matrix is symmetric, and the diagonal will be zero, you don't need to loop twice over each row so you can cut the looping down by over half:

```
for(i in 1:(nrow(df)-1))
{
  for(j in (i+1):nrow(df))
  {
    dist_mat[i,j] <- sum(df[i,1:4]!=df[j,1:4])  
  } 
}

dist_mat[lower.tri(dist_mat)] <- dist_mat[upper.tri(dist.mat)]
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have thought about this approach. Because of the next steps I perform, I need to produce the whole matrix.

Comment: @Chris It does produce the whole matrix, but since it is symmetric, you only need to do half and then copy it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for `combn`:

```
DF <- data.frame(x=rep(1,6), y=rep(1:2,3))

combn(seq_len(nrow(DF)), 2, FUN=function(ind, df) {
  c(ind[1], ind[2], sum(df[ind[1],]!=df[ind[2],]))  
}, df=as.matrix(DF))
```

Note that I convert the data.frame into a matrix, since matrix subsetting is faster than data.frame subsetting. Depending on your data types this could become a problem.

If your distance measure wasn't so unusual, `dist` would be helpful (and fast).

Comment: thank you for your answer. That is correct, dist would have saved my time if it was not for my distance measure.                              Sorry if I am missing something but I didn't understand your answer. I was expecting a `6 x 6` matrix containing the pairwise distance. But what `df` produces is a `3 x 15` matrix. Could you explain  your answer please? Thanks!

Comment: You have 15 measures in the upper (or lower diagonal); this is what is in the third column.