# How to customize outer and Vectorize functions?

Tags: r, matrix, distance, apply

I had asked a similar question a month ago. Please refer to 
[Count the occurrences of unequal numbers from a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073142/count-the-occurrences-of-unequal-numbers-from-a-data-frame/22073564?noredirect=1#comment33527626_22073564)

I solved that problem using `outer` and `Vectorize` functions. My solution is as follows:

```
dist_mat<- outer(1:nrow(df),1:nrow(df), 
                FUN = Vectorize( function(i,j) sum(df[i,]!=df[j,])))
```

This works perfect but now I have a huge matrix that exceed my memory size.

After I get `dist_mat`, for each row I count the number of columns less that or equal to two, which I can't do now. So, I am wondering if I can combine the count operation in outer function to avoid memory problem. My result would only be a vector.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does Roland's answer in the other question also have memory issues? [Edit to my comment upon further thought: it probably does, as it's only reduces the operations by a little less than half but adds two more columns.] That would be one way to fix the memory issues; if so, vectorized operations could probably used somehow to get the desired counts.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't strictly answer your question, you should probably avoid `outer` and use something like:

```
tot.rows <- nrow(df)
res <- numeric(tot.rows)
for(i in 1:tot.rows) 
  for(j in 1:tot.rows) 
    res[[i]] <- res[[i]] + (sum(df[i,] != df[j,]) <= 2)
```

`outer` will pre-allocate the `i * j` matrix from the get go, so you're going to have a hard time fixing the problem while using outer.  If your result is really a vector the same length as the data frame, then you don't need `outer` which produces a matrix of dimensions `nrow(df) * nrow(df)` in your application.

The above algorithm will run the same number of computations as `outer`, but re-uses the same memory space for each row since all you care about is the final counts, so it should fit in memory.  **It should also be of comparable speed as outer** (it is for the toy example I tested it with).  Vectorized operations are great so long as you actually need to compute on every value, and have the memory to deal with full expansions like `outer` does, but they are not necessarily the answer to everything.

As others pointed out in the previous answer, you could modify the code so that you don't calculate the diagonals or one of the triangles of the matrix given your distance calculation is symmetric, which should roughly halve computation time.

Comment: I had tried this before I went for vectorize. I don't have memory problem but it runs for several hours. Probably for days (I stopped it after 6 hours or so).

Comment: @Chris, the `outer` version should run just as slow.  Did you compare performance of the two approaches on a subset of your data small enough to fit in memory?  Also, it seems you really want to limit the calculations to the ones that are strictly necessary then.  Do you have duplicates in your data?  What is your data (numeric, factor, character)?

Comment: you are right, outer is also slow. I have a factor data type. I am now trying to find a way to reduce my data.

Comment: `outer` is fast if you feed it a function that is really vectorized instead of using a hidden `mapply` loop (via `Vectorize`).

Answer (score 1):

If you've got a matrix DF then

```
apply(DF, 2, function(y) sum(colSums(DF==y) < 2))
```

might work?  `DF==y`  compares each column to a target column from the `apply`, `colSums` then finds out how many of the rows in that column-pair are equal, and we compare that to 2 (a target column always gets compared to itself as part of the DF==y, so I've factored that in - you might need to play around with that, depending on whether your '2' threshold included self-self comparisons).  And then the final `sum` counts the number of columns that satisfy the <2 threshold.

It's entirely re-factored the code on the assumption you don't need the intermediate distance matrix.

Comment: There might be features of your data that could make things more efficient, as well.  e.g. You could remove rows that don't have any duplicate values using `apply(DF, 1, anyDuplicated)==0` - what are the dimensions of df - are there lots of column combinations, or is it the length of the columns?

Comment: Gavin, I think OP is trying to compare rows, not columns, and it seems you're doing the opposite here (I think?)?

Comment: A`DF <- t(DF)` should sort that, unless I've interpreted it as columns at one step and rows at another, which is entirely possible!  And it's probably worth benchmarking which works best on the OPs data, as we don't know whether it's long and thin, or short and wide, and the prevalence of duplicates etc.